# What does "Ribbono Shel Olam At" mean?

Tags: words, hebrew, shemos-sacred-names, aramaic

What does "Ribbono Shel Olam At" mean?

Comment: רבונו של עולם Ribbono Shel Olam == Master of the World

Comment: Is that even what you are asking?

Comment: Hello Arnulfo and welcome to Mi Yodeya.  Is your question what the phrase "ribbono shel olam" means, or are you also asking something additional?  Thanks, and I look forward to seeing you around.

Comment: Arnulfo, where did you see this expression?  Is the word "at" part of the expression you saw?  "Ribbono Shel Olam" means "Master of the World" in Aramaic (an ancient language closely related to Hebrew), which is used in many places in Jewish literature.  "At" means "You", so the entire expression would mean "You are the Master of the World", but I'm curious to know if you saw this in a Midrash or elsewhere, and who said it (I assume they said it to G-d).

Answer (score 2):

"Ribbono shel Olam" is a reference to G-d as the Creator and Master of the universe. See http://www.ou.org/about/judaism/r.htm#ribbono